# How to hide multiple (thousands) rows in the html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hide, show

I have html page with many rows (is about 40000)

```
<html><body>
<table id="t1">
<tr id="r1" name="1"><td>row 1</td></tr>
<tr id="r2" name="1"><td>row 2</td></tr>
....
<tr id="r50000" name="3"><td>row 30000</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

I need a fast way to hide/show set of rows (10 000 or 20 000) with the specified name. Platform requirements: IE8-9 and Mozila Firefox. I tray many methods: using tbody, block tags, hiding rows, and stop at one: loop trow the rows and  hide/show it:

```
curLevel=root.getAttribute("Name");
var nextElement=curElement.nextElementSibling;
while(nextElement!=null)
{
   curElement=nextElement;
   nextElement=curElement.nextElementSibling;


   if(curElement.tagName=="TR")
   {
      i++;
      childLevel=curElement.getAttribute("Name");
      if(childLevel<=curLevel)
       break;
      curElement.style.display = blockStyle;
   }
}
```

But this method is very slow!! Takes is about 2 minutes...
Loop goes fast, the slowest part is `curElement.style.display = blockStyle;` it repaints document every time. 
Could I change **display style**  for selection rows and then show changes?

P.S. without jQuery

Comment: Try to search for DataTables. Its an API that can menage thousands and evem millions of records and works in server-side, load then in browser and more effectively if you wanna load less than 3 seconds

Comment: Take a look at suggestions in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392068/delay-rendering-of-dom-element-when-changing-properties

Comment: @dfsq, it has good ideas. 1. clone table, than modify it and replace child...

Comment: @bcesars , thanks,  but DataTables is jQuery library, isn't  it?

Comment: I would just store my data in an array of objects. Then use `document.createDocumentFragment()`, append about 50 or so <tr>s to it based on the array of objects with an offset, and replace the tbody with that. The DOM is what's slowing you down, so the solution is to store it in an array until you actually need to see the records. Hell at that point you could just ajax in the next/previous 50, if it isn't already cached.

Comment: @rpc1 Yes. It's a library. But don't be afraid trying to use it. Its more simple than you can imagine and you only have to define in a js function `dataTable`.

Comment: @bcesars, I can't use jQuery libraries it's technical requirements

Comment: What is the value of *blockStyle*? To display rows that have been hidden using `display = 'none'`, it is best to use `display = ''` so they adopt their default or inherited value, which for TR elements is *table-row*, not *block*.

Comment: @RobG, displayStyle =''/'none' depends of show/hide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the fastest way is to use a CSS rule, either by adding and removing a rule, or modifying one. Since the rows you wish to hide have a common name, you can use the equivalent of the following to hide the rows with a name of "1":

```
tr[name="1"]{
  display: none;
}
```

and remove the rule to show them. The following shows how to do that.

```
// Object to hold functions for adding and removeing style rules
var myStyles = (function() {

  // Use the first style sheet for convenience
  var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

  // Delete a rule from sheet based on the selector
  function deleteRule(selector) {

    // Get rules
    var rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules; // Cover W3C and IE models

    // Search for rule and delete if found
    for (var i=0, iLen=rules.length; i<iLen; i++) {

      if (selector == rules[i].selectorText) {
        sheet.deleteRule(i);
      }
    }
  }

  // Add a rule to sheet given a selector and CSS text
  function addRule(selector, text) {

    // First delete the rule if it exists
    deleteRule(selector);

    // Then add it
    sheet.insertRule(selector + text);
  }

  // Return object with methods
  return {
    'addRule': addRule,
    'deleteRule': deleteRule
  };
}());

// Convenience functions to hide and show rows
function hideRows(){
  myStyles.addRule('tr[name="1"]','{display: none}');
}
function showRows(){
  myStyles.deleteRule('tr[name="1"]');
}
```

Alternative behaviours for the *addRule* function if a rule with the selector already exists are:

1. do nothing, or
2. add the new CSS text to the existing rule

Some play HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr name="1"><td>name is 1
  <tr name="1"><td>name is 1
  <tr name="1"><td>name is 1
  <tr name="1"><td>name is 1
  <tr name="2"><td>name is 2
  <tr name="2"><td>name is 2
  <tr name="2"><td>name is 2
  <tr name="2"><td>name is 2
</table>

<button onclick="hideRows()">Hide rows named 1</button>
<button onclick="showRows()">Show rows named 1</button>
```

Clicking on the first button hides all rows with a name of "1" by adding a CSS rule, clicking the other button shows them by removing the rule.

Of course you can make it much more sophisticated, the above just shows the method.

Answer (score 0):

a table with 40000 rows is not the best for a webpage....
like **pradipgarala** say you should do it from server side.

or at list use "divs" to separate multiple tables with less rows..

```
<div id="table_1_1000">
    <table>
    ...rows from 1 to 1000
    </table>
</div>
```

like this you can show-hide only the divs you need... and the loop would be faster...

but still not the best solution....

Comment: But I can't group rows in separate tables, it could by any rows... I think about it

Comment: how do you produce the 40000 rows.... is it a static html file or is a result of Database query and PHP ? ..... please add more detail.

Comment: it produces from the server side (using jsp + tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to do something like this:

```
var start = 20000; // hide 10k rows
var end = 30001; // rows from 20k to 30k
while(end!=start) {
    end--;
    var x = 'r' + end;
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
}
```

Basically, I would use IDs instead going trough DOM Nodes, if possible. It's "cheaper".

Since performance is an issue, you should note that is faster to decrement than to increment.

Note: Since I don't have enough rep, I can't comment on **pradipgarala**s answer so I'll note it here... Can you do something like **IF** "request is to hide/show over 10k(or whatever number your benchmark show you) rows" SEND REQUEST TO SERVER **ELSE** DO YOUR THING ON CLIENT SIDE?

Comment: "*Basically, I would use IDs instead going trough DOM Nodes*" not necessarily. Live NodeLists can be slow, but *querySelectorAll* returns static lists that should be as fast as an Array. Re "*…is faster to decrement than to increment*". Not any more, it's slower in some browsers. Do some tests on jsperf perhaps (there are probably quite a few already there testing that, e.g. [*Loops - increment vs decrement*](http://jsperf.com/loops-increment-vs-decrement/5)).