# Hide multiple span element (span_0_1, span_1_1, span_2_1) from a column html table

Tags: html, html-table

Hide multiple span element (span_0_1, span_1_1, span_2_1)  from a column html table

```
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
<th>S.No<th>
<th>Data 1<th>
<th>Data 2<th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><span id='span_0_0'>1</span></td><td><span id='span_0_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_0_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_1_0'>2</span></td><td><span id='span_1_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_1_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_2_0'>3</span></td><td><span id='span_2_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_2_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_3_0'>4</span></td><td><span id='span_3_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_3_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please add the code, so it can be easy for the community to help you

Comment: This question possibly has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090764/css-for-hiding-multiple-columns-in-a-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide multiple (thousands) rows in the html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453677/how-to-hide-multiple-thousands-rows-in-the-html-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is, that all of your spans are starting with `span_`. So, `$('[id^="span_"]').hide()` will hide all of them.
You could maybe hide only all spans with `span_1` like this:
`$('[id^="span_1"]').hide()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#span1').click(function() {
    $('span').show();
    $('[id^="span_"]').hide();
  });
  $('#span2').click(function() {
    $('span').show();
    $('[id^="span_1"]').hide();
  });
  $('#span3').click(function() {
    $('span').show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <th>S.No</th>th>
    <th>Data 1</th>th>
    <th>Data 2
    </th>th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id='span_0_0'>1</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_0_1'>my Data 1</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_0_2'>my Data 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id='span_1_0'>2</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_1_1'>my Data 1</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_1_2'>my Data 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id='span_2_0'>3</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_2_1'>my Data 1</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_2_2'>my Data 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id='span_3_0'>4</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_3_1'>my Data 1</span></td>
      <td><span id='span_3_2'>my Data 2</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<span>some other span</span>
<br />
<span id="nospan_0_0">span with other id</span>
<br />
<button id="span1">Hide "span_"</button>
<button id="span2">Hide "span_1"</button>
<button id="span3">show all</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
$("#spanitem_1_1").hide() ;
```

You can specify multiple elements by separating them by a comma.

```
$("#spanitem_1_1, #spanitem_3_1").hide() ;
```

or

```
$("span[id='spanitem_1_1']").hide() ;
$("span[id='spanitem_1_1'], span[id='spanitem_3_1']").hide() ;
```

Comment: And this is an answer to what question? Since he has not told the question.

Comment: I am telling him how he can hide an element by referring to it's id using javascript

Comment: this will make code static. I want something dynamic

Comment: @BikashNayak Can you clearly write the question above?

Comment: Please post your full code, so I can help you, and also make the question more clear

Comment: @Amit , i have dynamic html table ,also having dynamic columns and dynamic rows . this is the scenario

Comment: @MarioA.Rawady, posting the full code is not possible

Comment: @BikashNayak And which rows do you want to hide ? and why ? And how do you know which rows to hide ?

Comment: This answer is not helping at all. `$('[id^="spanitem_"]').hide();` should do the trick. We cannot assume why it is not working. @BikashNayak please make a breakdown of the problematic code and post it. Otherwise, no one will be able to help you

Comment: @BikashNayak Edit your question, and write what you need clearly, otherwise others will downvote and close the question very soon.

Comment: @MarioA.Rawady rows can go upto 1 to N, but columns is set to 1,

I want to hide the span element in the each cell of first Columns

Comment: @MichaelWalter  
<tbody>
<tr><td><span id='span_0_0'>1</span></td><td><span id='span_0_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_0_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_1_0'>2</span></td><td><span id='span_1_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_1_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_2_0'>3</span></td><td><span id='span_2_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_2_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id='span_3_0'>4</span></td><td><span id='span_3_1'>my Data 1</span></td><td><span id='span_3_2'>my Data 2</span></td></tr>
</tbody>